# Hibernate-search elasticsearch data indexing is synchronous or Asynchronous

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

We are implementing hibernate-search elasticsearch in our project and need a clarification.

After em.persist if the transaction is committed, is the data indexed into elasticsearch in a sync mode or async mode. Basically will the method return after the em.persist commit or will it ensure the data is indexed in elasticsearch. In the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_NGnbON3xAo at 17:30 I hear that the data is put on a queue and will be indexed in es in batch after db commit. So if elasticsearch indexing fails for some reason I might want to implement a manual db rollback so that the data is in consistent state in both the stores

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please take the time to separate questions into actually separate questions, and search for similar Q&A before posting new questions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm more interested to understand the save behavior. With the search I did a quick test and deleted couple of records in db. After executing a match_all the query returned records only present in db and ignored the additional one's in Elasticsearch.

Comment: And another update I stopped the elasticsearch docker instance after my service was up and tried a em.persist, received the  HSEARCH000058: Exception occurred org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH400007 but the data was successfully persisted in DB. So I believe the ES indexing happens on a seperate thread. Is there a property setting which can first index onto elasticsearch and then to DB??

Comment: Thanks for updating it; you could clarify the question a bit more though ;) "need clarifications on below two questions" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data is sent to Elasticsearch on commit, either synchronously or asynchronously depending on your settings.

If you're interested in changing those settings, have a look at the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-worker

**EDIT:** Also, even in synchronous mode, Elasticsearch is "near-real-time", meaning even if the changes have been processed, they won't be visible until a small period of time after your changes. So you might also have a look at the `hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.refresh_after_write` configuration setting. From the docs:

> Whether to perform an explicit refresh after a set of operations has been executed against a
>   specific index (true or false)
>
> `hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.refresh_after_write false`
>   (default)
>
> This is useful in unit tests to ensure that a write is visible by a
>   query immediately without delay. This keeps unit tests simpler. You
>   should not rely on the synchronous behaviour for your production code
>   except in rare cases as Elasticsearch is optimised for asynchronous
>   writes: leave at `false` for optimal performance.

Comment: @Raj Added some details about how to get strict synchronous behavior in Elasticsearch, but at the expense of performance.